# Dead lettering with php-amqplib and RabbitMQ?

Tags: php, rabbitmq, php-amqplib

I'm just starting out in using php-amqplib and RabbitMQ and want a way to handle messages that, for whatever reason, can't be processed and are nack'd.  I thought that one way people handle this is with a dead letter queue.  I'm trying to set this up but have not had any luck so far and hope someone could offer some suggestions.

My initiation of the queues looks a little something like:

```
class BaseAbstract
{
    /** @var AMQPStreamConnection */
    protected $connection;
    /** @var AMQPChannel */
    protected $channel;
    /** @var array */
    protected $deadLetter = [
        'exchange' => 'dead_letter',
        'type' => 'direct',
        'queue' => 'delay_queue',
        'ttl' => 10000 // in milliseconds
    ];

    protected function initConnection(array $config)
    {
        try {
            $this->connection = AMQPStreamConnection::create_connection($config);
            $this->channel = $this->connection->channel();

            // Setup dead letter exchange and queue
            $this->channel->exchange_declare($this->deadLetter['exchange'], $this->deadLetter['type'], false, true, false);
            $this->channel->queue_declare($this->deadLetter['queue'], false, true, false, false, false, new AMQPTable([
                'x-dead-letter-exchange' => $this->deadLetter['exchange'],
                'x-dead-letter-routing-key' => $this->deadLetter['queue'],
                'x-message-ttl' => $this->deadLetter['ttl']
            ]));
            $this->channel->queue_bind($this->deadLetter['queue'], $this->deadLetter['exchange']);

            // Set up regular exchange and queue
            $this->channel->exchange_declare($this->getExchangeName(), $this->getExchangeType(), true, true, false);
            $this->channel->queue_declare($this->getQueueName(), true, true, false, false, new AMQPTable([
                'x-dead-letter-exchange' => $this->deadLetter['exchange'],
                'x-dead-letter-routing-key' => $this->deadLetter['queue']
            ]));

            if (method_exists($this, 'getRouteKey')) {
                $this->channel->queue_bind($this->getQueueName(), $this->getExchangeName(), $this->getRouteKey());
            } else {
                $this->channel->queue_bind($this->getQueueName(), $this->getExchangeName());
            }
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            throw new \RuntimeException('Cannot connect to the RabbitMQ service: ' . $e->getMessage());
        }
        return $this;
    }

    // ...
}
```

which I thought should set up my dead letter exchange and queue, and then also set up my regular exchange and queue (with the getRouteKey, getQueueName, and getExchangeName/Type methods provided by extending classes)

When I try to handle a message like:

```
public function process(AMQPMessage $message)
{
    $msg = json_decode($message->body);
    if (empty($msg->payload) || empty($msg->payload->run)) {
        $message->delivery_info['channel']->basic_nack($message->delivery_info['delivery_tag'], false, true);
        return;
    }

    // removed for post brevity, but compose $cmd variable

    exec($cmd, $output, $returned);
    if ($returned !== 0) {
        $message->delivery_info['channel']->basic_ack($message->delivery_info['delivery_tag']);
    } else {
        $message->delivery_info['channel']->basic_nack($message->delivery_info['delivery_tag']);
    }
}
```

But I get back the error `Something went wrong: Cannot connect to the RabbitMQ service: PRECONDITION_FAILED - inequivalent arg 'x-dead-letter-exchange' for queue 'delay_queue' in vhost '/': received 'dead_letter' but current is ''`

Is this the way I should be setting up dead lettering?  Different examples I've seen around all seem to show a bit of a different way of handling it, none of which seem to work for me.  So I've obviously misunderstood something here and am appreciative of any advice. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Setting up (permanent) queues and exchanges is something you want to do *once*, when deploying code, not every time you want to use them. Think of them like your database schema - although the protocol provides "declare" rather than "create", you should generally be writing code that *assumes things are configured a particular way*. You could build the first part of your code into a setup script, or use [the web- and CLI-based management plugin](https://www.rabbitmq.com/management.html) to manage these using a simple JSON format.

The error you are seeing is probably a result of trying to declare the same queue at different times with different parameters - the "declare" won't replace or reconfigure an existing queue, it will treat the arguments as "pre-conditions" to be checked. You'll need to drop and recreate the queue, or manage it via the management UI, to change its existing parameters.

Where run-time declares become more useful is when you want to *dynamically* create items in your broker. You can either give them names you know will be unique to that purpose, or pass `null` as the name to receive a randomly-generated name back (people sometimes refer to creating an "anonymous queue", but every queue in RabbitMQ has a name, even if you didn't choose it).

---

If I'm reading it correctly, your "schema" looks likes this:

```
# Dead Letter eXchange and Queue
Exchange: DLX
Queue: DLQ; dead letter exchange: DLX, with key "DLQ"; automatic expiry
Binding: copy messages arriving in DLX to DLQ

# Regular eXchange and Queue
Exchange: RX
Queue: RQ; dead letter exchange: DLX, with key "DLQ"
Binding: copy messages from RX to RQ, optionally filtered by routing key
```

When a message is "nacked" in RQ, it will be passed to DLX, with its routing key overwritten to be "DLQ". It will then be copied to DLQ. If it is nacked from DLQ, *or waits in that queue too long*, it will be routed round to itself.

I would simplify in two ways:

- Remove the dead letter exchange and TTL from the "dead letter queue" (which I've labelled DLQ); that loop's likely to be more confusing than useful.
- Remove the `x-dead-letter-routing-key` option from the regular queue (which I've labelled RQ). The configuration of the regular queue shouldn't need to know whether the Dead Letter Exchange has zero, one, or several queues attached to it, so shouldn't know the name of that other queue. If you want nacked messages to go straight to one queue, just make it a "fanout exchange" (which ignores routing keys) or a "topic exchange" with the binding key set to `#` (which is a wildcard matching all routing keys).

An alternative might be to set `x-dead-letter-routing-key` to the name of the *regular* queue, i.e. to label which queue it came from. But until you have a use case for that, I'd keep it simple and leave the message with its original routing key.

Comment: PS: Hi Andy! ;)

Comment: Hi!! :-D  Didn't see this reply at all, sorry!  Great feedback and I'm all for simplifying things, so I'll give that a shot, thanks!